# in python: variables as indexes to slice an array doesn't work

Tags: python, arrays

So I am trying to get a slice of an array using variables for indeces, but not working. If I hard code numbers into the indeces it all works fine. Why???

My code:

```
def play(startplay,stopplay):


    Y = x[startplay:startplay+5]
    # produces an empty list...

    Y = x[1:5]
    # produces the correct list
```

Comment: First off, if `startplay` is `1`, then `Y = x[1:6]` not, `[1:5]`.

Comment: Well x isn't defined... what's the error. Please don't ever just say "not working" how are we supposed to know what that means?

Comment: Also, we have no idea what `x`, `startplay` and `stopplay` are, so please post sample values that  you are using so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of `startplay`? If it's longer than the `list` (or negative, but close enough to 0 that `startplay+5 >= 0`), you'd expect to get an empty `list` when you slice.

```
>>> test = [1, 2, 3]
>>> test[-5:0]  # Can't slice from negative to non-negative with implicit step of 1
[]
>>> test[-6:-1]
[1, 2]
```

As noted in the comments, your example is mismatched anyway; `x[startplay:startplay+5]` is a slice of length 5, `x[1:5]` is a slice of length 4.

Answer (score 0):

Im with ShadowRanger on this one. I see that the operation is supposed to work and does work in the example I created below.

```
def trial(x1, x2):
    array = [1,2,2,3,4,5,6,6,3,2,2,1,1,23,3,4,5,2,3,2,]
    new_array = array[int(x1):int(x2)]
    new_array2 = array[x1:x2]
    print(new_array2)
    print(new_array)
trial(1, 3)
[2, 2]
[2, 2]
```

Make sure that your list is capable of the operation first... Build up from hard examples and reference the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

Comment: Thank you for at least trying to duplicate my problem. You were right I was passing variables out of range for the original array. Dumb question but again I appreciate your response.

Comment: Not a problem.]

Comment: If you ever feel like an answer was valid, you need to provide appropriate up-voting and down-voting. If you deem your question 'dumb' all-together, you should remove it.